# Inversions with "so" and "such"

Tags: inversion

I got how to inverte sentences with so but I ask this question in order to make it conformed that inverting sentences with such does not work in the same way exactly.

For example:

> > They were so excited that they couldn't sit still. So excited were
> >     they that they couldn't sit still.
>
> or
>
> > It was so beautiful that we could not sit at home. So beautiful was
> >     day we could not sit at home. ( is the inverted sentence correct?)
>
> but how about sentences with such
>
> > It was such a beautiful day we could not sit at home. Such was a
> >     beautiful day we could not sit at home. ( is the inverted sentence correct?)
> >
> > Don has such a big house that it is a little ridiculous. Such a big
> >     house has Dan that it is a little ridiculous.( is the inverted sentence correct?)
> >
> > Such was their excitement that they began to jump up and down. And how
> >     can we rewrite this sentence ?

---

> Such was the wind that we couldn't open the window. 
>   The wind was such that we couldn't open the window. ( I took it from a grammar book)

In this example, does the word such mean "so great"  or "this type of...", if it means ""this type of..."

then only the sentences with such can inverte in which such implies "this type of..." or "that type of..." .

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

"So beautiful was day we could not sit at  home." is not the inversion, and is not grammatically correct. Try "So beautiful was it THAT we could not sit at home." This is still unnatural, but is a faithful inversion of "It was so beautiful that we couldn't stay home." Although you might think "day" is implied in the original non-inverted sentence, it is not stated. (I might think "weather" was implied, but I would not insert that into the inverted sentence either!)

As for "Such was a beautiful day we could not sit at home.", this is also not grammatical, and not the proper inversion. What you need is :  "Such a beautiful day was it that we could not sit at home". Again, not natural, but properly inverted.

The "such a big house" one is correctly inverted. Very unnatural, but correctly inverted.

The next one could be inverted thus:
"Their excitement was such that they began to jump up and down".

So, sentences with either kind of "such" can be inverted, even though some such inversions might sound unnatural.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct.  Informally, "such" is used to mean "so great", but the inverted version is not common.  For example, the following is common in informal speech:

```
It was such a beautiful day we could not sit at home.
```

but the following is not:

```
Such was a beautiful day we could not sit at home.
```

You will hear modified versions like this, however, though again, this is informal:

```
Such a beautiful day, we couldn't sit at home!
```

Comment: To elaborate on the last example by Jay, the complete form is likely "Such a beautiful day *it was that* we couldn't sit at home!"