# So were we, or, so we were

Tags: grammar

In Friends TV show series there's a conversation between Carol and Ross:
Carol: I cant speak for Emily but Susan is in a loving, commited relationship. 
Ross: Carol, so were we.

I think Ross should have said : Carol, so we were.

Am I wrong? Why Ross said: so were we.

Comment: 1) https://www.grammaring.com/subject-auxiliary-inversion-after-so-adverb-adjective-and-such          
2) https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/46520/inversions-with-so-and-such

Answer (score 1):

Ross said it right, because English language uses the invert form in this case, which is supposed to mean the following: something that I do the same.
Other verbs can also be used in this form:: have, is, are, am, do, did etc.

Answer (score 0):

Ordinarily you'd be right, but this is one of those cases where English speakers commonly [invert the subject and the verb](https://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/inversion.html), for example:

> Amelia:  I just love old romantic movies.
>   Beatrice:  So **do I**!

Unfortunately I can't find any references that specifically document this kind of usage.  I'll keep looking to see if I can dig up something.